# How to receive data join multicast group on UDP using ionic?

Tags: sockets, udp, ionic-framework, multicast

I have a LAMP server that write data on local network using UDP in multicast on port 300.
I'm developing an application using ionic framework for ios and android that have to read this data on UDP in multicast.
Is possible to do it? I'm trying socket.io library without success..how i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need a Cordova native plugin to achieve that.
[There seem to be one](http://www.girish.in/cordova-plugin-for-udp-messages/), but I never tried it yet.